# SQL return conditional

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I do to select all or nothing using SQL, following the condition: If any tuple has a column with the value 1 it must return empty, however if all have the value 0 it return all tuples.

Comment: if any row has **any** column with a value 1?, or a particular column?

Comment: What is the structure of the table? Please include all relevant columns.

Comment: If you're looking for a generic solution that works no matter what the table structure is, you'll have to use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable t WHERE t.MyColumn=1)=0
```

The condition evaluates to true or false for all rows; if any row has `1` in it, no rows would be returned.

Comment: This is only checking one column, when I believe the question infers there are multiple columns all of which need to be checked.

Comment: @Yuck Although the OP's intentions are not 100% clear from the statement, but the `WHERE` clause can be easily extended with `OR t.MyOtherColumn=1 OR ...` to include other columns into consideration.